# Combining horizontal and vertical lists on one board

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Right now, I can either have the list orientated horizontally or vertically, but what I would like to do is have both where I can have a horizontal line of list and have some stacked vertically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain a little more.  A single list of cards can only be displayed in one way at at time.  All lists in the same board are all displayed in the same way.  Are you suggesting you want to line cards up in both ways across multiple lists?

Comment: @Kevan - it would be good to be able to drag some lists and place them underneath others. For instance, let's imagine I have a board to manage the next version of my software product. I have 12 lists spread horizontally across my page. However, some of those lists will be completed concurrently, while others will be completed consequetively. I would like to drag the lists that will be completed consequetively underneath the lists they are reliant upon. This will in effect mean that you need to support lists spread both horizontally and vertically on a board.

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for.  I do not think Trello currently supports stacking lists vertically.

Answer (score 3):

Someone recently added this option to [Vertical Lists for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vertical-lists-for-trello/aldklnbenbdgfgfbflalmlddkkndgnlc) (a Chrome extension I created). It might not be as full featured as you're looking for, but it will now alternate the board arrangement between horizontal, vertical and "grid".